# Why cron adds question mark after log file name

Tags: 14.04, cron

I have created cron task using crontab but I get question mark at the end of log file name.

```
*/4 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path_to_cron/queue.php > /path_to_log_file/queue.txt
```

Is there any way to get read of it? The created file has question mark at the end it e.g. `queue.txt?`

I have tried to change the cron editor but it doesn't help

I can see by `crontab -l | cat -tve` that after each task there is `^M$` after log file name.

Comment: `^M` is a carriage return, and often signifies that there's a Windows style line ending. Did you copy and paste or otherwise move the cron entries from a Windows box? The `$` typically shows up in certain editors where it would normally wrap, but wrapping is disabled. Try widening your terminal window to see if it goes away. What editor is your default out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1):

As stevieb suggested in the comment above, you seem to have a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) at the end of your crontab line.

Here’s a recipe to get rid of it using the editor vi. The following command will open the crontab for editing in vi:

```
VISUAL=$(which vi) EDITOR=$(which vi) crontab -e
```

Now enter `:%s/\r$//` and press Enter. That should remove all the carriage return characters at line ends. Then enter `:wq`, again followed by pressing Enter. That should save the crontab and quit the editor.

Comment: Why not just `VISUAL=vi`? `VISUAL` has precedence over `EDITOR`, so there's no point to setting both.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is not with editor. The problem is what @stevieb commented on mu question

Comment: @muru Thanks, I didn’t know this; where is this documented? I just wanted to make sure that no other editor is used to make my recipe work.

Comment: @Fury I agree that this is the problem, that’s why I have stated that in the first sentence of my answer. The rest of the answer gives you a recipe to solve that problem. The recipe also has the advantage (over your own answer) that no root access is required.

Comment: @Chriki See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/crontab.1.html

Comment: @Chriki Take a look at this please http://serverfault.com/questions/738368/why-cron-adds-question-mark-after-log-file-name/738428#738428

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

> The `^M` you're seeing is an extra [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) from Microsoft
>   Windows format. You can get rid of it by converting the carriage
>   return characters from DOS to Unix format using `dos2unix` utility.
>
> Here's an example that converts all user's crontabs:
>
> ```
> sudo dos2unix /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*
> ```

[Reference](https://serverfault.com/questions/738368/why-cron-adds-question-mark-after-log-file-name/738428#738428)